# Trailhead - Create a Lightning Component Question

Tags: trailhead

For the Create a Lightning Component Project on step 8 it says to 
"Switch from the `Recently Viewed` list to `All Accounts` and click to open the account for `United Oil & Gas Corp.`"
I have followed all previous steps but cannot find this account, I thought it might be under account name or account owner alias so I looked through all 1001 accounts but could not find the United Oil and Gas Corp account. The section is estimated to be completable in 5 minutes but I've been at this for about an hour now, if anyone can help that would be great, thank you!!

Comment: Try to just search for this object using the search bar on top?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to verify the step by following the instructions on another account. As a side note, I had that account in one of my other playgrounds, so you may get that sample data while following another trail.